# How return callback from a query made with node-oracledb?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, plsql

The following code is the same code used in the node-oracledb GitHub examples, called [select1.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/select1.js). I just modified it a little bit.

```
module.exports = function()  {
    var oracledb = require('oracledb');
    var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

    this.queryDB = function (query) {
        oracledb.getConnection({
            user            : dbConfig.user,
            password        : dbConfig.password,
            connectString   : dbConfig.connectString
        }, function(err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }
            connection.execute(query, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                    doRelease(connection);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(result.metaData);
                console.log(result.rows);
                doRelease(connection);
                return result.rows
            });
        });

        function doRelease(connection) {
            connection.release(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used as follow:

```
require('./dbquery.js')();
console.log(queryDB("SELECT * FROM users"));
```

I expected to see the same 2D matrix (representing the table) as on line "**console.log(result.rows);**". But the "**console.log(queryDB("SELECT * FROM users"));**" returns "**undefined**".

How can I return a value that I get in the callback function?

I tried to add a variable X at the beginning, like this:

```
module.exports = function()  {
    var oracledb = require('oracledb');
    var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

    this.queryDB = function (query) {
        var X;
        oracledb.getConnection({
            user            : dbConfig.user,
            password        : dbConfig.password,
            connectString   : dbConfig.connectString
        }, function(err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }
            connection.execute(query, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                    doRelease(connection);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(result.metaData);
                console.log(result.rows);
                doRelease(connection);
                X = result.rows
            });
        });

        function doRelease(connection) {
            connection.release(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                }
            });
        }
        return X;
    }
}
```

But this is still undefined. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's running in `async` nature. You can resolve it with `callback` or `promises`. You can't get value like this.

pass the `callback` and return with callback

```
module.exports = function(callback) {//pass callback function and return with this
  var oracledb = require('oracledb');
  var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

  this.queryDB = function(query,callback) {
    oracledb.getConnection({
      user: dbConfig.user,
      password: dbConfig.password,
      connectString: dbConfig.connectString
    }, function(err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return callback(err);
      }
      connection.execute(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          doRelease(connection);
          return;
        }
        console.log(result.metaData);
        console.log(result.rows);
        doRelease(connection);
        return callback(null, result.rows)
      });
    });

    function doRelease(connection) {
      connection.release(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return callback(err);
        }
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! But I still couldn't manage to use it. It should be something like: queryDB(function (callback){ console.log(callback); }); ?

Comment: No, callback first argument is error and second argument is result.

queryDB(function (err,callback){ console.log(callback); })

Comment: You also need to pass `query` while calling this function as you mentioned  in function defination

Comment: Yes. So, at the end it will be queryDB("select * from", function(err, callback){ console.log(callback); });

Comment: Thank you ! But can it be that it gives an error ? The TypError is: "callback is not a function". 

Your solution should work.

Comment: I updated answer, pass callback in your function defination

Comment: You are the boss ! Thanks a lot ! :D